# Fix closure allocations in enumerable lambdas in c#

Tags: c#, closures, heap-memory

I have DPA plugin in Rider and it shows me some closure allocations in lambdas.

I know what closure is and why there is. I know why `c_DisplayClassxx` is created.

But my question is - how to change code to fix it?

Mostly my problem is in enumerables `Where`, `FirstOrDefault`, ... I don't know how to write predicates to avoid closure allocations.

Here is example - closure gets all 5 parameters and it consumes huge amount of memory.

```
    public IList<RequirementMappingRule> FindItems(ProductFilterMap productMapItem, 
        RuleProviderContext context)
    {
        var financialCompanyCode = productMapItem.Product.Product.FinancialCompanyCode;
        var parentRiskCode = productMapItem.ParentRiskCode;
        var riskCode = productMapItem.Risk.Risk.Code;

        var ruleCandidates = Items.Where(r =>
                (r.CompanyCode == financialCompanyCode || r.CompanyCode == "*")
                && r.ParentRiskCode == parentRiskCode
                && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.RiskCode) || r.RiskCode == riskCode)
                && r.IsValidByRiskValue(productMapItem, context))
            .ToList();
         
        // etc. ...
}
```

**UPDATE**: Just to clarify my question - Closure captures financialCompanyCode , parentRiskCode, etc. I want to know if there is any pattern how to avoid whole closure or not. I think using `Where` and parameters always ends with closure and generating `DisplayClass`, so only way to fix it is not to use `Where` and use `foreach` or `for` to get items.

Am I right?

Comment: `r.IsValidByRiskValue(productMapItem, context)` look at this function and maybe change it so you don't need to pass the whole context

Comment: Yes, it is function, but it is not important. Closure captures financialCompanyCode , parentRiskCode, etc. I want to know if there is any pattern how to avoid whole closure or not. I think using `Where` and parameters always ends with closure and generating DisplayClass, so only way to fix ot is not to use Where ans use `foreach`.

Comment: A closure by itself is not necessarily problematic, it depends how much it's holding on to. Furthermore, if you execute the lambda immediately and don't hold to it then eitehr way it shouldn't be a problem. Why do you think "it consumes huge amount of memory", what is your basis for such an assertion? Have you run a memory profiler and it shows a big object graph hanging off that lambda?

Comment: This function is part of `hot path` so is called many times. Every call ends with a new instance of DisplayClass and because of parameters used in `Where`, memory is allocated (bad design, for example context is not simple value, etc.) and not disposed imediately. So I need to rewrite code, yes, but just want to know if there always will be closure or Where can be writen without closure.

Comment: LINQ is not that great in very hot paths precisely because of the closure issue. No there is no way to rewrite it while still using LINQ because you need some way of capturing that data. Your only option while still using LINQ is using a rewriter as part of your build, see https://mattwarren.org/2016/09/29/Optimising-LINQ/